# I am trying to add a spinner in my android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

I'm trying to add a spinner to my android app but gives me this error(Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.) and this part (MainActivity.this,) has a red line under it when the cursor is under it says 'com.example.myapplication.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class. I'm doing this from another activity not from the main activity. No changes in the MainActivity.
AddEmployee class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employee);


        Spinner myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter myAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
       myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        myspinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Provide complete code that you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

try with like this

```
List<String > strings = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strings);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid context, so you should use your current activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employee); 
          Spinner myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

          ArrayAdapter myAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(SecondActivity.this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
          myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          myspinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
      }


}
```

or you can use `this` or `getApplicationContext()` instead of `MainAcitvity.this`
but I prefer to use `this`

Answer (score 0):

`createFromResource`'s first parameter is context. You can get context in two way:

1. Application Context: `getApplicationContext()`
2. Activity's Context: `ActivityName.this`

Application context is general context of project, you can get it from all activity. 
Activity contexs are specific to the activity. So you can access it from only it's own activity. You tried to access an activity context from another activity so it gave this error. You can try `getApplicationContext()` or `AddEmployee.this`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example :

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener 

    {

 String[] item_list= {"Select your option", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};

  @Override

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employee); 

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, item_list);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
  }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```